Android Studio flows logcat with strange error message
For some reason logcat of my app is flawed with same error message:
com.google.android.apps.betterbug Package [my.package.name] reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.
I do not understand why this is started to happen and how to resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.
The log message appears to be posted from different services:

com.android.systemui E  Package reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.
16:31:58.672  6708-6708  ActivityThread          com.android.systemui                 E  Package  reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.
16:32:40.116  3338-3338  ActivityThread          .ShannonImsService                   E  Package  reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.
16:32:40.117  3338-3338  ActivityThread          .ShannonImsService                   E  Package  reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.
16:33:34.033  5374-5374  ActivityThread          com.google.android.apps.turbo        E  Package  reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.
16:33:34.036  5374-5374  ActivityThread          com.google.android.apps.turbo        E  Package reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.
16:34:17.519  6226-6226  ActivityThread          com.google.android.partnersetup   

Tried reinstalling. Happens only on real device.

Same. I think it is due to the Koala update

Android Studio will helpfully try to uninstall an existing application instance on the target device, except it doesn't seem to be completely working anymore.  Disconnect device, uninstall app via Play Store, restart device, reconnect, relaunch Android Studio.  That cleared the errors for me.  HTH.

I don't know why it is occurring, but the following logcat filter gets me the results I am after:
package:mine -message:"reported as REPLACED"


This is not a solution to the problem. It is just a filter that hides those messages. Like when you cover your eyes with your hands and say "you can't see me!". But of course you're still there. It does not help at all.

No, it's not a solution. It is a work-around.

It's not a work around either. It's just a way to shoot the messenger without changing anything.
